# How to insert date and user_id to mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm quite new in PHP and MySQL. I tried to make message board where user can post some message on wall and the every logged user can read it.

Now when someone add message doesn't write in table author_id and date_added. I need them when results are displayed.

Here is new.php

```
if(isset($_POST['formSubmit']))
{
    $errorMessage = "";

    if(empty($_POST['formTitle'])) 
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>Doesn't have title!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($_POST['formContent'])) 
    {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>The field for content is empty!</li>";
    }

    if(empty($errorMessage)) 
    {
        $db = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
        if(!$db) die("Error connecting to MySQL database.");
        mysql_select_db("homework3" ,$db);

        $sql = "INSERT INTO massages (author_id, date_added, title, content) VALUES ('$_POST[author_id]', '$_POST[date_added]', '$_POST[formTitle]', '$_POST[formContent]')";
        mysql_query($sql);

        header("Location: index.php");
        exit();
    }
}

<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<div><label for='formTitle'>Title<input type="text" name="formTitle" value=""   style="width: 350px;"></label></div></br>

<div><label for='formContent'>Content</div><textarea name="formContent" style="width: 344px; height: 100px;"></textarea>

<input type="submit" class="formbutton" name="formSubmit" value="Send"/>

</form>
```

Edit:
I don't know if you need this but this is how I display massages:

```
$sql = 'SELECT username, msg_id, title, content, date_added FROM massages as m, users  as u WHERE author_id = user_id ORDER BY m.date_added DESC';

  $result = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $real_date = date('d.m.Y', $row['date_added']);
    echo '<table>
   <tr>
   <td>' . $row['msg_id'] . '. ' . $row['title'] . '</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
     <td>' . $row['content'] . '</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
<td>By<span style="color: #CC0033;">' . $row['username'] . '</span> on   <span style="color: #CC0033;">' . $real_date . '</span></td></br>
</tr>
</table>';
}
```

}

Comment: [Please, don't use mysql_* functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php) in new code. They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about prepared statements instead, and use [pdo](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation) or [mysqli](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mysqli).

Comment: @Goro had you save the author_id in session?

Comment: $_SESSION['username']

Comment: ok I have updated my answer. http://stackoverflow.com/a/19176360/829533 check it and see if it works

Comment: also if you dont have started the session in this page, do `session_start();` in the top of the page

Comment: so the problem is solve now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hidden attributes i.e. `type = 'hidden'` for auther_id

For example in your form

```
<form action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post">
<div><label for='formTitle'>Title<input type="text" name="formTitle" value=""   style="width: 350px;"></label></div></br>

<div><label for='formContent'>Content</div><textarea name="formContent" style="width: 344px; height: 100px;"></textarea>

<input type="hidden" name="author_id" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['what_ever']; ?>"/>
<input type="submit" class="formbutton" name="formSubmit" value="Send"/>

</form>
```

**NOTE:** `<?php echo $_SESSION['what_ever']; ?>` is just an assumption of how your `author_id` could be

and for **date_added** you can create add this directly in the query no need to post it via form

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO massages (author_id, date_added, title, content) VALUES ('$_POST[author_id]', NOW(), '$_POST[formTitle]', '$_POST[formContent]')";
```

You should also avoid sending `author_id` via post and add it rather in this manner

```
$auther_id = $_SESSION['username'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO massages (author_id, date_added, title, content) VALUES ('$auther_id', NOW(), '$_POST[formTitle]', '$_POST[formContent]')";
```

**IMPORTANT**

PHP is deprecating the `mysql` functions you must need to use `mysqli`
[Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/829533)

Answer (score 2):

When author login, Store `author_id` in session.

```
$author_id=$_SESSION['username'];
```

Then store it in database.

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO massages (author_id, date_added, title, content) VALUES ('$author_id', 'NOW()', '$_POST[formTitle]', '$_POST[formContent]')";
```

**NOTE**

Don't forget to start the session on the top

```
<?php
    session_start();
    // then your all code
```

Comment: @zzlalani yes it will work, it returns data and time in `YYYY-MM-DD h:i:s` format

Comment: Because when I tried it with quotes `"'NOW()'"` it says `Warning: #1264 Out of range value for column 'date' at row 1`.. and added `0000-00-00 00:00:00` in the row.

Comment: @zzlalani yes don't add any quotes, it will work without quotes

Comment: NOW() write only year (2013)

Comment: @Goro it depends on the data type of your field. if it is set to `year` it will save year only and if it is set to `datetime` or 'timestamp' it will save it as `YYYY-mm-dd H:i:s`

Comment: @Goro you need `datetime` field to store date

Comment: Oh, yes i forgot about this. I will change it now. But still problem with author_id .. is 0 on every new add.

Comment: @Goro this is because you are not storing user in session. do you have implement login system?

Comment: Date is ok now. I edited my question a little with how I display the massages.

Comment: @Goro which session variable you are using for author?

Comment: $_SESSION['username']

Answer (score 1):

In your table change author_id to auto increment, No need to add it in INSERT query.

Try below change:

```
$date_added = date('Y-m-d');

$sql = "INSERT INTO massages (`date_added`, `title`, `content`) VALUES ( '$date_added', '$_POST[formTitle]', '$_POST[formContent]')";
mysql_query($sql);
```

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments, you should avoid using the `mysql_*` commands, however the problem is with the following line:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO massages (author_id, date_added, title, content) VALUES ('$_POST[author_id]', '$_POST[date_added]', '$_POST[formTitle]', '$_POST[formContent]')";
```

In order to embed an array variable in string you have to surround it with braces, eg.

```
"{$_POST['author_id']}"
```

BUT you should not do this in your example as it would leave you wide open to a mysql injection attack. The old way of dealing with this is to escape each of posted variable using `mysql_escape_string()`, but the better way of dealing with this is to use the PDO Data objects e.g. http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindvalue.php